# Unable to figure out why the scale_x_continuous function in ggplot is not adding tick marks

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sorry for the newbie question, but I can't find the answer to this anywhere using a Google search. I am working through a beginner R open course and the directions were to create the below plot using ggplot2 and mark the x-axis every 2 units. I am using the scale_x_continuous function and using the same format as I see in examples online. However, the below code actually removes all the tick marks from the x-axis except for the limits. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, depth)) +
     geom_point() +
     scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,19000,2))
```

Comment: You want to use `breaks = seq(0,19000,2)` although I doubt you really want increments of 2.

Comment: Are you sure you want to label the x-axis every 2 units? Given the range of `price` this seems like a silly idea.

Comment: Alternatively can use `breaks = 2*0:9500`

Comment: `c(0, 19000, 2)` gives you a vector with the values 0, 19000, and 2, i.e. those are the only tick marks that will be drawn. `seq(0, 19000, by = 2)` gives you a vector of the numbers in a sequence from 0 to 19000 by increments of 2.

Comment: @Jay That was it, thanks for everyone's help and the extra detail in explanation camille. Agreeing the ticks at every 2 units in this question seemed strange - realized later that the question probably intended the variables to flipped on the axes, so the argument is actually breaks = seq(0,80,2) which makes much more sense. Regardless, your answers helped me understand the function better!